S3 Multipart Upload throwing the size requirement error. Possibly not recognising the last part correctly
I am trying to upload a file via multipart upload to S3 from my react native app.
If the file is more than 1 part (part size is 5MB and last one being less than 5mb) I am getting the following error:
"Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size".
But it works fine for the files smaller than 5mb. What's confusing me that I am using the same code for the mutlipart upload from the web app where this works fine and I don't get the size error.
I correctly generate parts e.g. 6 parts for a 26mb file.
What possibly can be the issue? It seems like it's not recognising the last part.

can you post a code snippet, so we can get a better idea, about how are you dealing with it.

Hi @mbnxx, kindly ensure that the partition factor for 6 parts embarked by 5MiB (5* 1024 * 1024 bytes)
